# Device cannot receive multiple notifications with FCM

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have gone through each and every step of Firebase Docs but the problem is

When sending multiple notifications and the end user's android device has its internet connection off, after switching on the Internet, the device is receiving only one notification, only the latest one.

This makes this feature of little or no use. 
Anyone experiencing the same?
How to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent

 pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
 NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.xchat_icon_push)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageBody))
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

  if (NOTIFICATION_ID > 1073741824) {
    NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;
  }
  notifManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID++, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Where to add this?

Comment: once created notification builder use this

Comment: Please expand on this. I am a novice with no previous programming experience.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: please check updated code in FireBaseMessagingService you have to put this code

Comment: @Anurag Mittal If your code is working in single notification then you have to just change Notification ID++ it will work for multiple notification

Comment: Thank you. Will inform is this works in a day or two. I am out of town right now.